# Can a person who was converted into half Ghoul by replacing parts of his organs be reverted to human by replacing those organs with human ones?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

In Tokyo Ghoul Kaneki was converted into a half Ghoul when he was transplated organs from a female Ghoul into his body. Can a person like him, who was converted into half Ghoul by replacing parts of his organs, be reverted to human by replacing those organs with human ones?

Comment: Its an interesting question. If the cause was an infection that spread through the body, then a person should eventually become a full ghoul. Unless some people are naturally immune to the infectious agent, in which case - half ghoul, or do they eventually heal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR Most likely not.

I will try to answer operating known facts, but description of ghouls biology in Tokyo Ghoul is vague, so I can't avoid some speculation. I might also accidentally drop spoilers of varying severity, so be cautious.

Kaneki has became half-ghoul after having kakuhou implanted. After this, he obtained all abilities available for ghouls, including regenerative powers, physical power, ability to use kagune etc. Which leads me to conclusion, that in regards of organs, **the main difference between humans and ghouls is kakuhou** (probably as main element to control RC cells, which are ensuring the rest of ghoul abilities).

So, maybe, we can reverse half-ghoul state by removing kakuhou? Doubtfully. In fight between Suzuya and half-ghoul twins Kuro and Shiro, Suzuya heavily damages Shiros kakuhou, and later doctor Kanou mentions, that such damage to kakuhou is lethal, and Shiro will be not able to recover (chapter 107 of Tokyo Ghoul). Which leads me to second conclusion - most probably, **kakuhou transplantation is irreversible**. This also makes sense in terms of RC cells - after becoming half-ghoul, persons RC cells level in blood raises significantly, and most probably, without kakuhou, excess of RC cells may lead to [ROS](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Rc_cell_over-secretion_disease) development.

Also, one note in regards of transplanting human organs to ghoul. If ghoul mother and human father will have a child, it was said that mothers body will mistake child for food and consume it. I don't think that transplantation will work in different way - most likely, human flash will be either consumed by ghoul body, or will be populated by RC cells to ghouls level.

Most likely, to make ghoul a human, it would be better to try to decrease RC cells level in their body, but it is not clear how it will affect ghouls altered physiology. If I remember correctly, RC suppresants not just suppress ghoul abilities, but also negatively affects their health.